# Choosing Photo's from Camera Roll on every device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I have an app that chooses an image from the Camera Roll or Takes a photo using the Camera. The problem is that when I run the app on an iPad, if I select an image it doesn't display the full image later on.

Image you select : [image: image selected] (Notice that the waterfall is pretty much  entered.)

Image displayed : [image: image displayed] (The image is displayed wrong)

The problem is only on big devices like iPads. I'm saving the image using CoreData and then recovering it. How can I get it to display the full I'm age?

Niall

Answer (score 1):

You need to set UIImageView contentMode to ScaleAspectFit

Comment: I tried that already but I still have the same problem. Image: https://postimg.org/image/hykhhxugh/